# Call promise several times

Tags: typescript

In my angular application I'm using a promise to call a method in my service but since i need to call it several times i'm calling it inside a for loop.

```
for(let item of this.arrayName)
{
   this.service.funcName(item.name).then(result => {                  
       //handle result                   
   }).catch(err => {                  
       //handle error
   });
}
```

but what happens when getting results from several calls at the same time? does promise knows how to handle it? does it handles each result separately? 
or do i need to lock code?
thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't "call a promise". You can call a function which returns a promise. Each invocation will (probably) return a separate promise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Promise "knows" how to handle it. It is the nature of JavaScript. The JavaScript Event loop runs on a single thread, when an IO operation (ajax, indexeddb, filesystem etc...) finishes, a callback is appended to the message queue which is continuously consumed by the event loop. This way you don't have to worry about any race conditions. Moreover the ECMAScript specification is carefully designed to hide every places where a race condition can occur.

And this is the reason why you must avoid writing blocking code. If your code blocks, the whole EventLoop is blocked. Nowadays it is really hard to create such blocking code in JavaScript, but still not impossible.

See [Concurrency model and Event Loop on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Answer (score 0):

What you doing is creating one promise for each item in this.arrayName.

This should work fine, as long as each the processing of each item is completely independent. But what you have to be careful about is that your code execution will continue beyond the for loop before the promises are resolved and subsequently processed. So you *may* want to wait for all promises to be fully resolved before continuing.

You can do this in something like the following :

```
Promise.all(this.arrayName.map(name => {
   return this.service.funcName(name).then(result => {                  
       //handle result                   
   }).catch(err => {                  
       //handle error
   });
})
.then(...) // all success - do success case
.catch(...) // some failed - handle error case
```

Answer (score 0):

What [Samir said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825439/258482) is correct. Every time you call the function, it calls the return statement `return new Promise(...)` (this is the expected way of using promises).

JavaScript also has the concept of closures, which closes means that the arguments that you pass to the function only show up in that execution of the function. All primitives (including object **references**  are "closed over", so when the loop changes `item`, it does not affect the previous function call.

The only question left to ask is whether you really want them all executing in parallel. The loop you have will execute all of them without waiting for the previous promise to resolve.

Since you are using Angular, check out Observables. They have a somewhat steep learning curve (you think differently when using them), but they are extremely useful once you learn them.

The introduction that helped me finally understand Observables is this: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754